# ATDI free map read with software

Tags: python, c++

I am interested in working with the freely available [ATDI MAPS](http://www.atdi.com/cartography/). The maps are provided for their proprietary software `ICS manager` or `ICS telecom`. I am involved in a project to develop a software in `c++` or `Python` to read these GIS maps. There are available libraries in `python` for `GIS` maps, but if I am not wrong they work with other file types.

The downloaded maps are `zip` files containing `RGE`, `RSO` and `RBL` files.

`Spain_25m.zip` for example contains `spain_25m.RGE`, `spain_25m.RSO`, `spain_25m.RBL`

As I am completely new in this field I dont know how to convert these files to standard GIS file formats.

Comment: Have you contacted ATDI about how to export their proprietary format to a standard GIS format in ICS Manager or ICS Telecom?

Comment: @Fezter, no but since they are a famous company I thought people know how to do it.

Comment: I suggest to put in your topic some how that your searching for file converting. And further more that you add some examples which file-typ you desire.

Comment: I think you should use ICS MAP SERVER Application .....

Comment: can you elaborate on how OP should use ICS Map Server?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question,  The OP doesn't want to use any ATDI products, and ICS Map server is an ATDI product...